# How can I proof the bijection between two sets?

Tags: functions, proof-writing

I have the following problem:

How can I solve this problem, I have no clue.

Of course I know the properties of an bijection and I belief I have to use the induction to solve this, because we have an finite set , and this smells like induction for me. But the main problem is, that I do not know how to write it down mathematically correct. A professor told me, that I should copy as many proofs I can, and the understanding will come, hope so.

P.S. This is no homework, its only an old problem from a test paper

P.P.S. I'm not a real student yet, just very interested, hope this is not a reason for not helping:)

Best regards

Justin

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "$F$ is the set of all two colors of $A$"?

Comment: If $0,1$ are colors, any $\{0,1\}$-coloring of $A$ is written out as a string of length $n$, and vice versa.

Comment: @MichalAdamaszek yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $\Bbb{A}_n$ be the set of possible bichromatic colorations of $A$  with $|A|=n$, and  $\Bbb{B}_n$ the set of binary numbers of lenght $n$. Let's call the colours $c_1$ and $c_0$. We can create a function from $\Bbb{A}_n$ to $\Bbb{B}_n$:

$$f:  \Bbb{A}_n \to \Bbb{B}_n $$

Clearly:

$$a \in \Bbb{A}_n \iff a=\{c_{i_1},...,c_{i_n}\} \ \ \ {i_j}=0,1 \ \  \forall j $$
$$b \in \Bbb{B}_n \iff a=\{{i_1},...,{i_n}\} \ \ \ {i_j}=0,1 \ \  \forall j $$

So we can construct $f$ this way:

$$f(\{c_{i_1},...,c_{i_n}\})=\{{i_1},...,{i_n}\}$$

Suppose for absurd that this function wasn't injective. This means that there exist two colorations $\{c_{i_1},...,c_{i_n}\} , \{c_{k_1},...,c_{i_n}\}$ with $i_1 \neq k_1 $ such that:

$$f(\{c_{i_1},...,c_{i_n}\})=\{{i_1},...,{i_n}\}$$
$$f(\{c_{k_1},...,c_{i_n}\})=\{{i_1},...,{i_n}\}$$

But for the construction of the function:

$$f(\{c_{k_1},...,c_{i_n}\})=\{{k_1},...,{i_n}\}$$

So:
$$\{{k_1},...,{i_n}\}=\{{i_1},...,{i_n}\}$$

But this means that $k_1=i_1$ and this is absurd. Since $f$ is injective and $|\Bbb{A}_n|=|\Bbb{B}_n|=2^n$ , $f$ is also surjective. So  $f$ is a bijection.

:)

Comment: Hello, that sounds good, but my problem here is to create a formal correct proof.

Comment: @Justin14 I modified the answer

Comment: Tank you, one question, what exactly is F and W in your proof? I try to understand what you intention is

Comment: @Justin14 $F=\Bbb{A}_n$ and  $W=\Bbb{B}_n$

Comment: @ Eureka Would there be a different if $A$ was an finite set?

Comment: @Justin14 No , they would be both countable